# Understanding Bremsstrahlung

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photons, x-rays, particle-accelerators

I have this problem:

> The Stanford Linear Accelerator can accelerate electrons to 50 GeV What is the minimum wavelength of photon it can produce by Bremsstrahlung? Is this photon still called an x ray?

I have solved the problem to get $\lambda = 2.48\times 10^{-17}$m but I have problems with the last question because the wavelength is not the wavelength for x rays, however in the solution of the problem it is said that every photon produced by Bremsstrahlung is an x ray, even if it doesn't have the wavelength of x ray, Is that true?

Answer (score 3):

You have a definition or terminology issue, not a physics issue:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray#Gamma_rays

Excerpt:

> There is no consensus for a definition distinguishing between X-rays
>   and gamma rays. One common practice is to distinguish between the two
>   types of radiation based on their source: X-rays are emitted by
>   electrons, while gamma rays are emitted by the atomic
>   nucleus.[56][57][58][59] This definition has several problems: other
>   processes also can generate these high-energy photons, or sometimes
>   the method of generation is not known. One common alternative is to
>   distinguish X- and gamma radiation on the basis of wavelength (or,
>   equivalently, frequency or photon energy), with radiation shorter than
>   some arbitrary wavelength, such as 10−11 m (0.1 Å), defined as gamma
>   radiation.[60] This criterion assigns a photon to an unambiguous
>   category, but is only possible if wavelength is known. (Some
>   measurement techniques do not distinguish between detected
>   wavelengths.)

For the purposes of passing your tests, I suppose it is best to use the definitions implicit in your textbooks or notes, but you should be aware of the ambiguity.

Comment: Also for long wavelengths. Synchrotrons can be used as a source for infrared spectroscopy. I would not call them x-rays, but it is  Bremsstrahlung.